# How to load node modules in beaker notebook?

Tags: node.js, ipython

I'm using beaker notebook and would like to use some external node modules - yet because beaker doesn't change the system path to the directory of the currently active file, my attempts to include `stream-filter` are met with the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'stream-filter'
Error: Cannot find module 'stream-filter'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at eval (eval at processCode (/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/beaker/1.4.2-1-ge55c059/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/config/plugins/eval/node/app/app.js:45:23), :5:14)
    at processCode (/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/beaker/1.4.2-1-ge55c059/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/config/plugins/eval/node/app/app.js:45:18)
    at /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/beaker/1.4.2-1-ge55c059/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/config/plugins/eval/node/app/app.js:32:28
    at callbacks (/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/beaker/1.4.2-1-ge55c059/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/config/plugins/eval/node/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/beaker/1.4.2-1-ge55c059/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/config/plugins/eval/node/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/beaker/1.4.2-1-ge55c059/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/config/plugins/eval/node/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
```

I'm wondering how to solve this problem. I tried `process.chdir('/Users/akivalipshitz/Developer/Computational_Linguistics')` to no avail, even though stream-filter is installed in `node_modules` in the same directory.

So how do people use node modules

Answer (score 0):

The context where the node code is eval'd is in your case

```
/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom//beaker/1.4.2-1-ge55c059/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/config/plugins/eval/node/app/app.js
```

So `require()` looks for a module in the `node_modules` folder there and then recursively up along the parent folders ([see docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)).

One solution (if you're only working on one project or use this module frequently across all your projects) would be to install your module there:

```
cd /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom//beaker/1.4.2-1-ge55c059/Beaker.app/Contents/Resources/dist/config/plugins/eval/node/app/
npm install stream-filter
```

Another (ugly) approach could be to build a long relative path in your require(). In your case something like:

```
require('../../../../../../../../../../../../Users/akivalipshitz/Developer/Computational_Linguistics');
```

Both cases it would mean that your code is not portable to another beaker instance. However, at least until a better solution is proposed this could get you along prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

as of this writing, the current version of Beaker allows you to import `npm modules` right from the `GUI`. Just click `notebook` -> `Language Manager` -> `Javascript`, then type the module names into `Loaded Libraries`. Beaker autocompletes from the `npm registry`.

This works both in the `electron` client and the cloud hosted version.

[image: language manager screenshot]